# Footer keeps going wrong places

Tags: html, css

My footer acts different on different pages.
It should be allways under my content and when there is too little content it should be at the bottom of the page. I dont want a FIXED footer, so I am not sure what position it should have..

This is the css

```
#footer {
margin-top: 200px; /* Height of the footer */
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer .row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

#footer .middle {
    background: transparent url(../images/footerachtergrond.svg) no-repeat center 5%;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.footerlogo {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

#footer .bottom {
    background: #c40129;
    color: white;
}
```

This is the html

```
<footer id="footer">
        <div class="row middle">

        </div>
        <div class="row bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-5">
                    <img class="footerlogo" src="{{ URL::to('/images/logo_typografics_white.png') }}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-7">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: This has come up many times before - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sticky+footer

Comment: @AlessioCantarella If i put it on absolute it will put my footer in the middle of my content if i have a lot of content on my page

Answer (score 0):

margin-top is for measuring the external distance to the element

The height property sets the height of an element.
also remove position-fixed

```
#footer {
    height: 200px; /* Height of the footer */
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: If I use this and I have little content on my page my footer comes under the content and the rest under the footer is white

Comment: remove the height and add the all content inside the footer if you no need actual height of footer

Comment: I mean the other divs above my footer with content .. so underneath the footer there is white space

Comment: check your content div has a margin-bottom, or padding-bottom

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear:both, your footer, don't forget to clearfix your container divs, 
For example 
add clearfix class to your footer div

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
}

<footer class="clearfix"></footer>
```

add clearfix to content divs too
remove all positions to your footer, you can use position relative, it will be ok